# Can someone show me how this algebraic expression is worked out fully?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I'm not sure how they went from $\frac{k2i(1)2i(2)}{\frac{d}{8}}$ to 32F?

I'm weak in algebra so if anyone has any reccomendations how I can improve in manipulating equations or websites and resources I would also appreciate it. Khan academy is not good for this from what i see.

Comment: I don't think this is an algebra problem.  What is $F$ and how does it relate to the other variables?  Is that a unit of measure?  It looks like the last line is Newtons per meter?

Comment: I understand the problem, just not the algebra bits. How did the first fraction, mathematically, equate to 32F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with

$$F'=\frac{kI_1'I_2'l}{d'}$$

The first thing that is done is that we replace the variables as defined 
$$F'=\frac{kI_1'I_2'l}{d}=\frac{k(2I_1)(2I_2)l}{\frac{d}{8}}$$
Now we can use the rule for division by fractions:
$$F'=\frac{kI_1'I_2'l}{d}=\frac{k(2I_1)(2I_2)l}{\frac{d}{8}}=k(2I_1)(2I_2)l\times\frac{8}{d}$$
Finally, we can pull all of the integers together to get
$$F'=\frac{kI_1'I_2'l}{d}=\frac{k(2I_1)(2I_2)l}{\frac{d}{8}}=k(2I_1)(2I_2)l\times\frac{8}{d}=\frac{(2)(2)(8)I_1I_2l}{d}=\frac{32I_1I_2l}{d}=32\frac{I_1I_2l}{d}=32F$$

Here I have assumed $F$ is defined as $\frac{I_1I_2l}{d}$. Perhaps another point of confusion: here the ' notation is being used to indicate a new variable and is *not* being used to indicate the derivative.